# Scale at which beta distributed variable breaks down to Bernoulli trials

Tags: binomial-distribution, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

This may just be a case where I'm not finding the right terminology.

Let's say I have $n$ random checkerboards of different (known) areas $A_i$ and squares placed with probability $p$ (white) and $p-1$ (black).  Each board has a known ratio $r_i$ of white squares (measured by, for example, the grey-scale value of a blurry picture of the board).  I can easily find the expected value of $p$ by

$E(p) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i \times r_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i}$

What I'm not sure how to calculate is the expected value of the area $x$ of each square for which each board breaks down into $\frac{A_i}{x}$ Bernoulli trials.

If $A$ were constant, I would expect $r \sim Beta(kp, k(1-p))$ and $E(x)=f(A, k)$ or $f(A, p, k)$ (which I could fit from Monte Carlo simulations if nothing else - for instance for large $k$, it seems $E(x) \rightarrow \frac{A}{k}$).

But since I'm not sure of the closed form for that (especially for smaller $k$), I have no idea how to find $E(x)$ when $A_i$ is not constant.

Comment: Does it mean that each checkerboard has a different size (in terms of number of squares)?

Comment: Another question: if you say "random checkerboard" do you mean randomly colored (black and white) or also having a random size (how many squares)?

Comment: Yes, each checkerboard is a different (known) size, and the size of the squares is constant  but unknown ($x$).  So each board has a different (unknown) number of squares that is linearly related to its size.  The randomness is in how the black and white squares are placed on each board.

Comment: Could you possible explain $k$?

Comment: since for a Beta distribution $p = E(Beta(a,b)) = \frac{a}{a+b}$, if you know $p$ there's only one degree of freedom in the Beta distribution, which is related to the other moments.  This I've called $k$, with $a = kp$ and $b = k(p-1)$

Answer (score 0):

First, let me summarize my understanding of the problem on an example.

Let's have the boards of the following shapes: $4\times 6$, $6\times6$, and $2\times 4$.

The following approach can be applied:

1. Determine the largest possible square. This is analogy to largest common numerator. In our case, it will be square $2\times 2$.
2. Using $r_i$, calculate the likelihood of each square size. Some of the square sizes will be excluded automatically, e.g. if $r_3=1/8$, the largest possible square size is $1\times1$.
3. Combine the likelihoods by means of Bayesian inference, possibly using flat prior for allowed square size.

Comment: This might  be a method for small, squarish boards, but my "boards" aren't necessarily square, and more importantly I expect $\frac{x}{A}$ to be smaller than the measurement error in $r$, so I can't work geometrically -  which in why I'm asking here instead of on math exchange.